# Java loads file with non JAR extension

Tags: java, jar, jvm, classpath

Here's my Java version:

```
# java -version
java version "1.4.2"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 2.2)
IBM J9SE VM (build 2.2, J2RE 1.4.2 IBM J9 2.2 Linux amd64-64 j9xa64142-20080130 (JIT enabled)
J9VM - 20071205_1933_LHdSMr
JIT  - r7_level20071016_1845)
```

(this is part of IBM Information Server)

There were some updates that I had to deploy to the live application so I had to replace one of the existing `jar` files. Obviously, I made a backup of the old `mylibrary.jar` file and I called it `mylibrary.jar.old`.

After starting the application, after several painful hours of debugging, I noticed that - for some reason - `mylibrary.jar` was not loaded and `mylibrary.jar.old` was actually loaded.

Indeed, both of them are located in the class path, but I was expecting that files with a non-JAR extension are not loaded. I am sure that this is what is going and I can reproduce the issue.

Am I missing something? I was not able to find anything on Oracle's website regarding this.

---

*EDIT:* I've also tested with Java from Oracle and the same thing happens.

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Check IBM's documentation, since your version info indicates you are using an IBM JRE, not a Sun/Oracle JRE.

Comment: What IDE are you using (if any?)

Comment: No, I'm not using any IDE. This is actually a JAR file part of the IBM Information Server 8.1 - http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_8.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.productization.iisinfsv.sdfnav.doc/dochome/iisinfsrv_home.html (ojb-conf.jar - if it's any relevance). This JAR is supposed to contain the database connection details.

Comment: Perhaps they are inspecting the file type (the file starts with PK followed by two specific bytes) rather than the name?

Comment: Yes, exactly, it's either that (most probably) or some Java configuration (?) that makes it autoload that file or the resources in it. Still, being a closed-source software (IBM Information Server) I can't really tell.

Comment: You must be running a script which includes all files in a directory. If you do this, that file will be included.

Comment: @Razvan - I realize that it's been a while, but - could you please post the actual reason for this behavior, if you ever managed to establish it? This question is creating a confusion as to what Java classpath does and does not do...

Comment: No, sorry, I simply removed the backup file from that folder and it worked fine. I guess the reason was: *All JAR files (even if extension other than .jar or no extension at all) in designated directories are loaded.* (there are some unofficial docs that mention this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually classes are loaded , not jars. [jar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jarGuide.html) is a type of zip format and `JVM` lazily loads classes by unzipping the jar.

With java [extension](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/) mechanism it is possible that JVM may load classes in a file ( zip ) that doesn't necessarily have a .jar extension.

The page [here](http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2014/10/java-extension-mechanism-loads-all-jars.html) explains in detail how a jar without even an extension could be loaded by VM.

Your old jar in the format `mylibrary.jar.old` can be perfectly unzipped. Test using `7-zip`. So JVM could load the classes when required from this old jar, now why doesn't it pick up from `mylibrary.jar` instead of `mylibrary.jar.old` ? I would guess it is because JVM default class loading might look into the jars by `Date Modified` and because already a class is found JVM doesn't bother look in other jars.

Also I would rather remove `mylibrary.jar.old` from your application and back it up somewhere else in the directory not specified in the java `classpath`.

Comment: Ok, so it seems that, probably, the Extension Mechanism is used and "*[..] All JAR files (even if extension other than .jar or no extension at all) in designated directories are loaded.*".